# How to alias singleton scope onto a custom scope in Spring

Tags: java, spring, scope, singleton, alias

Ok so I have a custom scope that works in a server environment. I'm trying to write some unit tests and in the case of the unit tests I want these beans to be singleton since it's too complicated to mock everything necessary to make the custom scope work.

I just want to do something like this

```
<!-- spring-test.xml -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.CustomScopeConfigurer">
    <property name="scopes">
        <map>
            <entry key="myCustomScope" value-ref="singletonScope"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I want to override my custom scope in the `junit` test and just have it be singleton. However there doesn't seem to be a `SingletonScope class` as it seems quite embedded in the framework, being the default and all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is relatively easy to write a Scope implementation that behaves like singleton scope, especially if you don't particularly care about destruction callbacks (but even then not that difficult).  I assume for testing purposes you care more about object creation than destruction so it should be just a matter of calling and caching the value from the ObjectFactory that you get handed in Scope.get().